# Line wrap not working in tmux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux, word-wrap

I am using `konsole-4.14.3`, `tmux-2.6` and my shell is bash. Outside tmux, line wrapping work perfectly and the text is moved to the next line. In tmux, this does not work though. I googled for a long time, but did not find any working fixes. In my `~/.bashrc` I have

```
export PS1="\[\e[1;92m\]\u@\h: \w \\$ \[\e[m\]"
export PS2='> '
```

I removed them and tried again, but the result was the same. I am on Slackware 14.2 and it seems that the problem is related to some system setting because with the same `~/.tmux.conf`, line wrapping works as expected on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Found the problem. It seems to be happening in bash 4.3, maybe older versions as well. The default value of `TERM` for my OS (outside `tmux`) was `xterm`. As soon as `TERM` is set to `screen` or `screen-256color`, line wrapping stops working. Since `tmux` requires that `TERM` is set to `screen` or `screen-256color`, line wrapping would not work. The problem was fixed after updating to bash 4.4.

Comment: Let's mention for the record that _inside_ `tmux` and `screen` the expected value of `TERM` is something related to `screen` (e.g. `screen-256color`), whereas _outside_ of `tmux` and `screen` it should be whatever the terminal emulator sets for you by default (often `xterm` or `xterm-256color`). Don't expect the same value (whatever it is) to work both outside and inside of tmux.

Comment: Experiencing this with Bash 5.0.3

Comment: Same on Bash 5.0.17(1)-release and tmux 3.1b

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue with bash 4.4, 5.0.17, and 5.1.