# Line wrap not working correctly in Tmux in Tmux in Mosh

Tags: terminal, tmux

I connect via Mosh on some server, and run Tmux there, which runs fine.

From there, I sometimes connect via SSH to other servers, and I might run another Tmux inside there. For most other servers, this is also working fine. Except for one server, where line wrapping seems to be messed up. At least sometimes. I haven't really figured out exactly when. When I use e.g. `man` or `less`, it happens very often.

This is how it looks:
[image: screen man]
[image: screen less]

Once I resize the window, it is redrawn correctly. However, once I scroll up or down (e.g. in `man`), it is messed up again.

I'm not really sure whether this is an issue with the inner Tmux or with something else.
<s>Without the inner Tmux, it is also working fine.</s> (Hm, now that is also broken, e.g. directly using `man`. Not sure if I changed sth now while playing around, and it was working before...?)

I already tried two different Tmux versions (2.7 and 3.3a), and I have the problem in both cases.

There are a couple of related reports:

- [Line wrap not working in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/1266577/line-wrap-not-working-in-tmux)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res/

They sound very related. However, none of that is really working for me. I'm also not using Bash but ZSH.